# Can we use commas within a phrase to combine many ideas into one?

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to say "with increasing the height, an increasing deviation can be seen."

Can I use the phrase *from lower part to upper* within commas as follows?

> Similar to above case, an increasing difference, from lower part to upper, with few large deviations can be seen from the second comparison.

Is there anything wrong with that sentence?

Answer (score 8):

> *¹Similar to above case, an increasing difference, from lower part to upper, with few large deviations can be seen from the second comparison.

The above has numerous errors, ranging from missing articles to ambiguity and semantic inconsistency.  For example, the use and placement of “can be seen” is a problem; do we group it as “large deviations can be seen” or as “can be seen from the second comparison” ?

You can substitute either  “from lower to upper” or  “from the lower part to the upper” in place of incorrect “*from lower part to upper”.  Or, just it leave out and say either of “as we go up, deviation increases” or “as height increases, so does deviation”.  These phrases are concise and are less obtuse than the incorrect “*with increasing the height, an increasing deviation can be seen”.

Instead of jumbling everything into one long muddled sentence, write simple and short sentences with clear meanings.

¹Asterisk denotes improper form